# Deleting a row in azure table - not working

Tags: javascript, sql, azure

I'm trying to delete rows of an azure table.
First I fetch the table then iterate over it deleting every item, the code is in JS:

```
 var basketTable = client.getTable("Basket");

                var query = basketTable;
                query.read().then(function (basketTable) {
                    basketTable.forEach(function (basketProduct) {
                        basketTable.del(basketProduct);
                    });
                });
```

In the debugger, I only see GET request for fetching the table, which was loaded, however, there was no DELETE request. I tried like this and by passing the id to the del function, still no success. I'm thinking I need something like saveChanges method, to actually delete the rows, because I think it just deletes the rows from in memory table. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing both the table operation and execution of the operation.

```
// Create an operation to delete the entity.
TableOperation deleteStuff = TableOperation.delete(basketProduct);

// Submit the delete operation to the table service.
tableClient.execute("people", deleteStuff);
```

Take a look at the *[How to use the Table storage service from Java](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-table-storage/#DeleteEntity)* doc.